# Mutli-step form issue

Tags: reactjs, multi-step

I am currently working on a multi-step form to post to the server and I am trying to the data using onChange as an event handler to get the data from the inputs. I used the following code to handle the input :

```
handleChange = input => e => {
        this.setState({ [input]: e.target.value });
    };
```

And in the form, I created an object to include data that need to be sent later to the server. And here is how I did this and then stored all values inside an object name values:

```
   const { first_name, last_name, phone, special_instructions, email, category, total_amount, delivery_date
            , delivery_address, pickup_address, source, payment_method, invoice_number,
            delivery_amount, delivery_address_id, pickup_address_id, pickup_date, invoiced_amount } = this.state;

        const values = {
            first_name, last_name, phone, special_instructions, email, category, total_amount, delivery_date
            , delivery_address, pickup_address, source, payment_method, invoice_number,
            delivery_amount, delivery_address_id, pickup_address_id, pickup_date, invoiced_amount
        };
```

The thing is when I try to enter data using the following line

```
<Input type="date" name="pickup_date" onChange={handleChange('pickup_date')} value={values.pickup_date} />

<Input type="text" name="nickname" onChange={handleChange('nickname')} value={values.pickup_address.nickname} />
```

The first one works pretty well and accepts input but the second one doesn't Idk why. Also, you can check the data of the values here :
[image: You can check the values data right here]

I hope that someone can help me to get both data that are inside the pickup_address and outside it.

Comment: Well the `handleChange` function doesn't know that the value of "nickname" needs to be stored inside of `pickup_address`, so you need to pass in anything to make sure it knows the correct nesting e.g. a second param like the object path as a string or something like that

Comment: As far as I can see, there is no state named `nickname`

Comment: It is inside an object called pickup_address which is already inside the values object.

Comment: And how can I add a second param?! That means I need to change the onChange too!

Comment: you need to extend your state as well such as this.setState({ ...state, [input]: e.target.value });